# Deriving from std::back_insert_iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, std

I want to derive from `std::back_insert_iterator` to create a kind of filter for a string type, say `back_xml_insert_iterator`, that will examine the characters passed through it looking for characters that can not be emitted "naked" into an XML stream, e.g., `'"'`, `'&'`, `'<'`, `'>'`, and `'\''`, and will on-the-fly insert their character entity references instead, e.g., `"&#34;"` for `'"'`.

```
template<class StringType>
class back_xml_insert_iterator : public std::back_insert_iterator<StringType> {
  typedef std::back_insert_iterator<StringType> base_type;
public:
  typedef typename base_type::container_type container_type;
  typedef typename StringType::value_type value_type;

  explicit back_xml_insert_iterator( StringType &s ) : base_type( s ) { }

  back_xml_insert_iterator& operator=( value_type c ) {
    switch ( c ) {
      case '"':
      case '&':
      case '\'':
      case '<':
      case '>':
        char buf[10];
        this->container->append( "&#" );
        this->container->append( itoa( c, buf ) );
        this->container->push_back( ';' );
        break;
      default:
        this->container->push_back( c );
    }
    return *this;
  }
};
```

This compiles fine.  When I create an instance, I confirmed that the constructor is called, but my `operator=()` is never called.  I think it's because the inherited `operator*()` returns a `back_insert_iterator&` and not a `back_xml_insert_iterator&` so `back_insert_iterator::operator=()` is called rather than mine (since `operator=()` is not, nor can not be, `virtual`).

If that's the case, then it seems impossible to derive from `back_insert_iterator` in a useful way.

If I instead create my own `back_insert_iterator_base` class like:

```
template<class ContainerType,class DerivedType>
class back_insert_iterator_base :
  public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag,void,void,void,void> {
public:
  typedef ContainerType container_type;

  DerivedType& operator*() {
    return *static_cast<DerivedType*>( this );
  } 

  DerivedType& operator++() {
    return *static_cast<DerivedType*>( this );
  }

  DerivedType& operator++(int) {
    return *static_cast<DerivedType*>( this );
  }

protected:
  back_insert_iterator_base( ContainerType &c ) : container( &c ) {
  }

  ContainerType *container;
};
```

and derive from that instead like:

```
template<class StringType>
class back_xml_insert_iterator :
  public back_insert_iterator_base< StringType, back_xml_insert_iterator<StringType> > {
  // ... as before ...
};
```

then `back_xml_insert_iterator` works as desired.  So is it possible to derive from `std::back_insert_iterator` and have it work as desired?

## Update

Here's how I'd like to use the `back_xml_insert_iterator`.  First, there would be the helper function:

```
template<class StringType> inline
back_xml_insert_iterator<StringType> back_xml_inserter( StringType &s ) {
  return back_xml_insert_iterator<StringType>( s );
}
```

Then writing a `to_xml()` function would be trivial:

```
template<class InputStringType,class OutputStringType> inline
void to_xml( InputStringType const &in, OutputStringType *out ) {
  std::copy( in.begin(), in.end(), back_xml_inserter( *out ) );
}
```

Comment: So you could also overload `operator*` to return a correct type?

Comment: @Everyone: Please see [stl's info tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=stl&sort=info) to see why I added [stdlib] to the question. I think it's a good idea to get into the habit of referring to the standard library correctly, hence my "do [stdlib]" proposal.

Comment: @UncleBens: yes, but then I'm overriding 50% of the member functions, so there's really not much point in deriving from back_insert_iterator in the first place.

Comment: @GMan: I disagree. "stdlib" is ambiguous as well. It refers to the *entire* standard library, much of which has *nothing* to do with the STL. When people say STL it is usually pretty safe to assume that they mean "the STL-derived portion of the standard library". Asking people to use `[stdlib]` instead *adds* confusion and ambiguity, it doesn't remove it. Apart from this, the term "STL" is used commonly by a large part of the std committee, so I feel most of the objections fall a bit flat. If the term is good enough for Herb Sutter and Scott Meyers, it's good enough for me

Comment: @GMan: unless of course you meant we should use `[stdlib]` for questions about the standard lib *in general*, without dropping the use of `[stl]` for the questions about the STL-derived part of the stdlib. In that case, I agree.

Comment: @GMan: I edited the tag info page (shame there's no edit history on it). How is this version?

Comment: @jalf: I indeed meant the latter, I see how it could be read others ways. [stdlib] should be added to any question that refers to something in the standard library, I think. (Your edit is clarifies this quite well.) Thanks. (And yeah, I wonder what the rationale for not adding an edit history is, it could be useful.)

Comment: @Paul J. Lucas:  Are you sure this isn't a job for `transform` used with a functor of your design?

Comment: @Dibling: (I could have sworn I responded to somebody else's comment on this.)  I don't see how a unary_function would work since it's not a simple char-to-char mapping.  For the relevant characters, it has to return a string.  Additionally, using back_insert_iterator even with transform() will try to use push_back() and std::string doesn't have push_back(char*).

Comment: @Lucas:  I'll try to post something that might work for you.  I could be misunderstanding the problem, but it seems to me a simple transform should do what you want.

Comment: @Lucas: Could you provide a snippet of code that illustrates how you intend to use the back_insert_iterator you're trying to create?

Comment: @Dibling: see Update to original question.

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to inherit from classes that were not designed with inheritance in mind. In general you should not inherit from standard containers or iterator. Note that in most cases the usage of iterators is in templates that do not require a type hierarchy in the first place.

It is usually better to add the functionality externally either by providing functors or else implementing your own iterator --which should not be really complex. You can take a look at the iterator adaptor library in boost if you really want to implement your own iterators.

Comment: Then why does std::back_insert_iterator have a protected section if you're not supposed to derive from it?  That's the confusing bit.

Comment: @Paul: you are right, it does have a protected section, but that is not in itself a reason to derive from it. You should derive from a class only *if it is the simplest, cleanest and most maintainable* way to extend it. Not just because you *can*. The class doesn't have a virtual destructor, which is usually a strong hint that users should *not* derive from it.

Comment: @jalf: Virtual functions do NOT typically occur in iterator classes. I don't think that's an indicator of anything.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It is an indicator that they are not meant to be used polymorphically. Maybe it would be better if the discussion is worded in terms of inheriting and expecting dynamic behavior. A class can be designed to be used as a base class with non-polymorphic behavior -- consider trait to be the biggest example there. But that won't allow you to use it polymorphically as it won't be possible.

Comment: @Paul J. Lucas: As I mentioned in the previous comment, I should have stated the issue better. Trying to be generic in the answer --avoid inheriting from classes not designed for it--, I missed the detail. A class in C++ can be designed to be inherited and yet not used polymorphically. There are few examples, but I guess this is one of them. The `protected` block is an indicator that the designer considered the class could be derived. The lack of virtual methods on the other hand, is a clear indicator that no polymorphic behavior is to be expected.

Comment: Certainly, no polymorphism. But iterators are typically used with template idioms. The only `protected` member of `back_insert_iterator` is `Container *container;`. If I wanted to distribute inserted elements among several containers, say round robin, it would seem necessary to use inheritance. Private inheritance would prevent any polymorphism confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive from `back_insert_iterator`, but you have to override the operators to return your derived type.

Does that render the strategy pointless? It depends on your coding style. The overrides will simply call the base method and return `this`, so you end up with a run of copy-paste code, much like what you put in `back_insert_iterator_base`.

```
template<class StringType>
class back_xml_insert_iterator : public std::back_insert_iterator<StringType> {
  typedef std::back_insert_iterator<StringType> base_type;
public:
  typedef typename base_type::container_type container_type;
  typedef typename StringType::value_type value_type;

    // add trivial overrides to avoid returning base type:
  back_xml_insert_iterator &operator++() { base::operator++(); return this; }
  back_xml_insert_iterator operator++(int) {
      back_xml_insert_iterator ret( *this );
      base::operator++();
      return ret;
  }

  explicit back_xml_insert_iterator( StringType &s ) : base_type( s ) { }

  ...
```

Of course, a similar block of code could implement passing operator calls to a *member* `back_insert_iterator`, which would eliminate the inheritance as others recommend. This is possibly a better approach.

Note that private inheritance, with `: private std::back_insert_iterator`, would add safety by preventing users from attempting to use your class as something it's not.

Comment: Yes, it's rather pointless to override all the members.  The point was hopefully to get code reuse.  Calling the base operator++() is also pointless since all they do it return *this.

Answer (score 0):

I could get this to work with the call to operator= successfully. Did I get it right?

// back_insert_iterator example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class StringType> 
class back_xml_insert_iterator : public std::back_insert_iterator<StringType> { 
   typedef std::back_insert_iterator<StringType> base_type; 
public: 
   typedef typename base_type::container_type container_type; 
   typedef typename StringType::value_type value_type; 

   explicit back_xml_insert_iterator( StringType &s ) : base_type( s ) { } 

   back_xml_insert_iterator& operator=( value_type c ) { 
      switch ( c ) { 
      case '"': 
      case '&': 
      case '\'': 
      case '<': 
      case '>': 
         break; 
      default: 
         this->container->push_back( c ); 
      } 
      return *this; 
   } 
}; 

int main () {
   vector<int> firstvector, secondvector;
   for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
   { firstvector.push_back(i); secondvector.push_back(i*10); }

   back_xml_insert_iterator< vector<int> > back_it (firstvector);

   back_it = 2;   // It does call operator=

   copy (secondvector.begin(),secondvector.end(),back_it);

   vector<int>::iterator it;
   for ( it = firstvector.begin(); it!= firstvector.end(); ++it )
      cout << *it << " ";
   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Did I get it right?" - You are missing that no library is going to assign a value to an iterator without dereferencing it. No code does `back_it = 2;`; all code does `*back_it = 2;`. If the latter doesn't work, you don't have an iterator.

Comment: @Uncle: This peculiar "extension" is part of the specification of inserters. See §24.4.2/3.